# QSettings - What is the way to read path value?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ini

Using windows xp, i want to read a value from .ini file.
The value is a path. 
Using QSettings, the result of the call to "settings.value("key").toString()" is the the path excluding backslashes, because backslash is escape character.
What is the way to read a path from ini file, using QSettings?

Comment: what value you want to read from `.ini` file ? where is it located ?

Comment: This the section and the value:

Comment: [Section]
key=C:\Qt\test.xml

Comment: Can you just use / instead as a path separator? Qt will be fine with that on windows or you can convert the path using QDir::toNativeSeparators()

Comment: I can not use '/' instead. I can not edit the ini file. I am not sure i can convert the path, since the the value i get is "C:test.xml".

Answer (score 3):

> Although backslash is a special character in INI files, most Windows applications don't escape backslashes () in file paths [...]
>
> QSettings always treats backslash as a special character and provides no API for reading or writing such entries.

This is what the documentation has to say about it. It is a polite way of saying "if some other code does it, they're not following the WINAPI spec and it's broken and we shouldn't have to deal with it". Pretty much your .ini files are broken.

If you wish to read them, you may need to provide your own backend for `QSettings`. Such a backend can be easily obtained by copying the one that comes as part of Qt, and modifying it not to perform escaping.

You'd need to investigate whether writing your own `QTextCodec` for this purpose and passing it to `QSettings::setIniCodec` would be sufficient. If sufficient, you wouldn't need to provide an entire backend.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize compatibility issues, any @ that doesn't appear at the first position in the value or that isn't followed by a Qt type (Point, Rect, Size, etc.) is treated as a normal character.
Although backslash is a special character in INI files, most Windows applications don't escape backslashes () in file paths
[enter link description here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/QSettings.Format.html)